# How to apply styles to props of multiple classes?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using [react semantic ui lib](https://react.semantic-ui.com/). I have multiple modals in my application with different classes. I don't want to setup styles for modal globally since some places it's not required. Initially, I had following styles:

```
.abc.ui.modal > .close {
  top: 1.0535rem !important;
  right: 1rem !important;
  color: black;
}

.xyz.ui.modal > .close {
  top: 1.0535rem !important;
  right: 1rem !important;
  color: black;
}
```

Then, I simplified up-to this:

```
.abc.ui.modal > .close,
.xyz.ui.modal > .close {
  top: 1.0535rem !important;
  right: 1rem !important;
  color: black;
}
```

Can I simplify this further? or can I avoid using `.ui.modal > .close` twice or more? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Due to specificity in CSS, you need those `.ui.modal > .close` rules in order to maintain higher specificity and get your styles to override the default styles in the Semantic UI classes. If you are only using CSS, then you have already optimized as far as you can go, which is great.

If you were using a CSS preprocessor like SASS you could optimize even further by doing something like this:

```
.abc,
.xyz {
  &.ui.modal > .close {
    top: 1.0535rem !important;
    right: 1rem !important;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

As a separate note, I would caution against using `!important` rules if at all possible as they can become extremely hard to override later on if you need to. Instead, I would recommend increasing the specificity of the rules are are writing so you do not need to use `!important` at all. Your future self will thank you for it.